# Weblogic 12.1.3 CDI Transactional

Tags: weblogic, cdi, jta, weblogic12c

Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done in order to enable CDI JTA Transactions using @Transactional annotation under CDI beans with Weblogic 12.1.3 server?

I have tried to just add the annotation into a service method, but EntityManager didn't recognize to be running under a transaction.

Is there any interceptor or something else that needs to be registered?

Comment: Weblogic 12.1.3 is a Java EE 6 container.  @Transactional was added in EE 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JoshAment is right.

WebLogic 12.1.3 only partially supports Java EE 7 (it supports its four pieces: `JPA 2.1`, `JAX-RS 2.0`, `JSON-P 1.0`, `WebSockets 1.0`). But `@Transactional` is a part of `JTA 1.2`.

Right now only Liberty Profile is fully certified against Java EE 7. 
The planned year-end WebLogic 12.1.4 is going to support it also.

Anyway, answering your question: just configured `persistence.xml` should be enough to use the `@javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation in your code.

// You may also consider to move away from Java EE 7 ;) then you would be able to freely choose whatever lib you want. I strongly believe that server itself should not provide anything except servlets.

Comment: WebLogic 12.2.1 supports Java EE 7 and was released last week ;)

Comment: @ArjanTijms Thanks for news although I'm surprised. I read earlier announcements which was saying about `12.1.4`.

Comment: Upvoted this answer cuz of the tip to move away from Java EE. It is helpful to read qualified opinions and not feel so alone in this world.